# ASP.NET MVC Razor language code

Tags: support, code-formatting

What language code in the language hint should I use for code blocks for ASP.NET MVC Razor views?

```
<!-- language: lang-razor -->
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md#user-content-for-which-languages-does-it-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I've come up with so far is just to not use the language hint on these code blocks, but tag the question with `asp.net-mvc` or `asp.net-mvc-4`. If I do that, it syntax highlights both the html and the c# in the razor code. It does not seem to work with `asp.net-mvc-5` question tag alone, however. A tag for the question highlights un-hinted code in the answers correctly as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not correct. The syntax of a language code should be:

```
<!-- language: lang-razor -->
```

However, Razor is not in the [list of supported languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: # December 2023 update: `lang-razor` is now fully supported https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77554464/2987689